# Consistent HTML table dimensions

Tags: css, html, html-table

I frequently find myself wanting an HTML document with two (or more) consecutive tables that I want to be formatted identically: with each column the same column width.  E.g.

```
<table>
  <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Identifier</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody><tr><td>John Smith</td><td>A-64</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
<p>Some text &hellip;</p>
<table>
  <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Id.</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody><tr><td>Xavier Ephraim Bloggs III</td><td>A-434-bcf</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

As it is, browsers will render the columns of the second table wider than those of the first, simply because the contents of each cell is wider.

I *could* fix this by hard-coding the widths of each column, either with the HTML `width` attribute, or (better) with CSS.  But I don't want to do that because I don't know how wide to make each column.  The correct width will depend on the user agent's choice of font, the width of the user's screen, and the content of each cell (which is itself generated from user input).  In any case, the UA is far better at deciding layout than I am.

What I really want is some way of saying to layout the second table as if it were a continuation of the first one.  I *could* do that by actually making them a single table, with the intervening paragraph as just another row (with enough CSS to make it not appear so), but that seems bad, evil and wrong.

```
<table>
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Id.</th></tr>
  <tr><td>John Smith</td><td>A-64</td></tr>
  <tr colspan="2"><p>Some text &hellip;</p></tr>
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Id.</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Xavier Ephraim Bloggs III</td><td>A-434-bcf</td></tr>
</table>
```

Logically it is one table, but one that I want rendering in several sections because it would otherwise be overly long.  That suggests that the logical way to encode the table is with two separate `<tbody>`s:

```
<table>
  <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Identifier</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody><tr><td>John Smith</td><td>A-64</td></tr></tbody>
  <tbody><tr><td>Xavier Ephraim Bloggs III</td><td>A-434-bcf</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
<p>Some text &hellip;</p>
```

Is there some sort CSS / HTML5 trickery I can use to move the second `<tbody>` (and a copy of its header) to after the paragraph?

Comment: This would seem unlikely to be achievable without JavaScript.

Comment: You're probably right, @DavidThomas.  But even a JavaScript solution would be good.  My attempt degrades really badly in a browser without JavaScript.

Comment: Could you post a live [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo so we can see what you're working with, and how it fails (a clear description of the failure, as well as the criteria for successful correction would be very, *very* helpful as well).

Comment: +1 for being averse to something "that seems bad, evil and wrong." I came here with the same question and the same aversion.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I concluded a CSS/HTML solution was impossible, but it could be done relatively simply with JQuery.

```
$( "table.splittable" ).each( function() {
    $(this).find("tr").first().children().each( function() {
        this.setAttribute('width', this.offsetWidth);
    } );

    var hdrs = $(this).find("tr.move-header");
    $(this).find("tr").each( function() {
        var tr = this;
        $( this.className.split(/\s+/) ).each( function() {
            var match = this.match(/^move-to-(.*)$/);
            if (match) { 
                var dest = $('#'+match[1]).get(0);
                if (dest.childNodes.length == 0) {
                    var thead = document.createElement("thead");
                    dest.appendChild(thead);
                    hdrs.each( function() { 
                        thead.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true)); 
                    } );
                    dest.appendChild(document.createElement("tfoot"));
                    dest = dest.appendChild(document.createElement("tbody"));
                }
                else dest = $(dest).find("tbody").get(0);
                dest.appendChild(tr);
            }
        } );
    } );
});
```

This script looks at every table with the `splittable` class, waits until the browser has rendered them and then adds a `width` attribute fixing the columns width to whatever the browser decided was optimal.  It then looks for every row with a class of `move-to-something` and moves it to the the table with and id of `something`.  If the destination table had no `<thead>` element, any rows in the source table with class `move-header` are copied there.

The result is that I need to put the content in a single table and put an empty place-holder table where I want the later line(s) moving:

```
<table class="splittable" id="table1">
  <thead><tr class="move-header"><th>Name</th><th>Identifier</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="move-to-table1"><td>John Smith</td><td>A-64</td></tr>
    <tr class="move-to-table2"><td>Xavier Ephraim Bloggs III</td><td>A-434-bcf</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>Some text &hellip;</p>

<table class="table2"></table>
```

Once the JavaScript has run, the second table gets a copy of the header and the last line is moved there.  Both tables have the same column widths.

It's a bit of an ugly solution, and doesn't degrade well in the absence of JavaScript.  But it's the best I've come up with yet.

Answer (score 0):

What about wrapping everything in a parent container, and using that to specify the overall width (which itself could be determined by either its parent or some kind of device/screen size rules).

You can then set the column widths to be a relative percentage (50% for 2 columns, 25% for 4 columns etc.)

```
table { width: 100%; }
td { width: 50%; }
```

See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/5q8Zc/

I also don't necessarily agree that 'Logically it is one table' - If both require a header and there is distinct content in between, it sounds like 2 to me, but it's difficult to judge without seeing the full page.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to avoid.  You've manually specified the width of the each column, and in the fiddle example (at least in my browser), the result is worse than in if it had been left to the browser.  The first column is too narrow, while the second is unnecessarily wide.

Comment: Then you are trying to impose too many constraints to make this possible to do simply with HTML/CSS. 

You are trying to make some columns scale to fit around their text content, yet others should scale to match the size of a column in a different table. What happens if a user decides to increase or decrease their text sizes? Your table widths will be all over the place.

In the example I gave, I have not, as you suggested, manually specified the width of each column. I have set a relative value which will be determined by the size of its parent.

Comment: You may be right that it's not possible in pure HTML/CSS, but you're wrong in the rest of the comments.  I don't want some columns to do one thing and others another: I want all the columns to the laid out as if they were part of a single table.  It's a fairly straightforward concept, and one that HTML rendering engines can clearly do because they can render a single long table.  And, yes, you are explicitly specifying the column widths by saying 50%.  Sure it's relative to the containing box, rather than absolute.  But it's specified nonetheless.